# How can I temporarily disable animation so that I can change parts of a character's body in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

Good afternoon.I have two layers in the animator for the upper body and for the lower, at one point I need to disable the layer for the upper body (for aiming the gun), so that I can adjust the current frame.How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can disable a layer by setting the **LayerWeight**.

```
 public float animWeight = 0.5f;
 public Animator anim;

 void Start () {
         anim.SetLayerWeight (2, animWeight);
 }
```

You should also be able to do this in the Inspector
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGeCZ.png)

You can find more informations under the following link from Unity
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html

Comment: Good afternoon.Everything is as you said, the animation is no longer playing, but I still can't move my hands while I need to aim

Comment: still latest the default layer will hold any property locked that is somewhere animated. The layers weight is just for blending them together but even with a weight of `0` or object is still under the control of the animator ...

Comment: Hi, when I played a bit with animation myself, this playlist helped me a lot: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLyBYG1JGBcd1E4CigRSDE9YdH8syiDY6-